# How to compare two TRect variables in D7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I compare two variables of TRect type?

```
var
  r1, r1: TRect;
begin
  if (r1 = r2) then
    ...
end;
```

With that above I get: Incompatible types.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you had a modern Delphi, then that code would compile and work. The `TRect` in modern Delphi versions takes advantage of operator overloading to overload the equality operator. You simply cannot make that syntax work in Delphi 7 since there is no built in equality operator for Delphi records.

Without that help from the compiler you need a helper function. You can write your own:

```
function EqualRect(const r1, r2: TRect): Boolean;
begin  
  Result := (r1.Left=r2.Left) and (r1.Right=r2.Right) and
            (r1.Top=r2.Top) and (r1.Bottom=r2.Bottom);
end;
```

Although, as @Sertac points out, there's little need to write your own `EqualRect` when you can use the [Windows API function of the same name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162699.aspx).

Comment: .. or use `windows.EqualRect`.